# Efficient way of replacing static method (200+) calls with non-static

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I was fixing a bug in our system. Here are the facts:

1. The bug sits in a method Yum() in a sealed class Noodles.
2. Bug method Yum() is a static method.
3. Yum() method is used 200+ times across code base.
4. Sealed class Noodles does implement a interface.

My question is that what is the best way of replacing the static method call with non-static calls without risking that it might break other code.

I want also be able to test Noodles class. As it is a sealed class and method is static, mocking option is out of window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where will the object come from to those 200 places?

Comment: Non-static calls to which instance?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot seems like OP in one place changed it to be non-static to make injectable and testable. But now they need to refactor everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea suggested by BlorgBeard is correct although you should implement a singleton pattern to achieve it. Jon Skeet wrote in his book a few [great examples](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) on how to implement the singleton pattern, giving several variants. As the example I'm picking I chose the Fifth Version - Fully lazy instantiation

In your specific case I would re-write your Noodles class in this way:

```
   public sealed class Noodles
   {
       private Noodles()
       {
       }

       public static Noodles Instance { get { return Nested.instance; } }

       private class NestedNoodles
       {
          // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
          // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
          static NestedNoodles()
          {
          }

          internal static readonly Noodles instance = new Noodles();
       }

       public static void Yum() {
          Instance.YumInternal();
       }

       public void YumInternal() {
       //Your code here
       }
  }
```

Concerning unit testing it's a bit trickier using sealed classes and static methods but it's not impossible. There are several approaches. One is using wrapper classes and given that your class Noodles already implements an interface it could be a solution. Another approach is using an isolation framework that permits mocking this types modifying the IL after compilation (Reflection.Emit, Mono.Cecil etc). Look at this [article](http://mattwarren.org/2014/08/14/how-to-mock-sealed-classes-and-static-methods/). Here is another [example](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MockSealedStatic.aspx).

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an instance of `Noodles` that you want to use across all calls, you could do a couple of refactorings (using Resharper or similar, preferably):

1. Extract the contents of `Yum` to `YumInternal`. Make YumInternal non-static.

   ```
   public static void Yum() {
       NoodlesInstance.YumInternal();
   }
   public void YumInternal() {
       // actual Yum code here
   }
   ```
2. Inline method `Yum`, so that each call to it is replaced with its contents.
3. Rename method `YumInternal` to `Yum`.